# Why method cannot return a boolean?

Tags: php, json, laravel, function

Here is my code:

```
public function shouldHaveOption(Request $request)
{
    return shouldHaveOption($request->option_key);
}
```

The result of `shouldHaveOption()` function is either `true` or `false`. And it throws:

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

Why should the returned value a string?

---

Noted that `return jsone_encode(shouldHaveOption($request->option_key));` would work. Because `jsone_encode` make a boolean to string.

Comment: Yes the response content cannot be boolean, so you can wrap it in an array: `[shouldHaveOption($request->option_key)]`.

Comment: Is `shouldHaveOption(Request $request)` directly called by a route ?

Comment: Try `return response(shouldHaveOption($request->option_key), 200);` why because in laravel you must return a response object always; normally when returning views or redirect using helpers, laravel converts it to response automatically but I guess it won't do that for booleans.